# Avoid ZeroDivisionError inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, exception

I have a function that I am trying to tweak to in order to avoid the `ZeroDivisionError`. The couple of methods I have tried have not worked out and I am looking for any help.

I have already tried adding the following to my code:

```
try:
 try:
 raise Exception("0")
```

However, that is not working and I am not sure what else I can add.

```
def complexDivide(list_of_numbers, index):
    denom = list_of_numbers[index]
    return [easyDivide(item, denom) for item in
        list_of_numbers]

def easyDivide(item, denom):
    return item / denom

complexDivide ([0, 2, 4], 0)
```

The goal would be to add something to the code that gives a list of [0, 0, 0] when there is a call to complexDivide.

Comment: How is the computer supposed to know what value you want when you divide by zero? Zero division is undefined in general math. If you want a value to be returned when you divide by zero, you'll have to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the result of division by zero to be zero, make it so:

```
def easyDivide(item, denom):
    return 0 if denom == 0 else item / denom
```

It might be faster to make the decision once in `complexDivide` instead of in `easyDivide`:

```
def complexDivide(list_of_numbers, index):
    denom = list_of_numbers[index]
    if denom == 0:
        return [0] * len(list_of_numbers)
    return [easyDivide(item, denom) for item in
        list_of_numbers]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. The code works when changed, but I am still not getting a list of [0, 0, 0] which is my ultimate goal. Am I missing something in my initial code that would bring that up?

Comment: I'm presenting two options. Choose one or the other. Both are not necessary.

Comment: Here is a link showing that both options behave exactly as you ask: https://ideone.com/pKnX4U

Comment: If you aren't getting what you want, please indicate what you are getting instead.

Comment: I think just returning 0 in case of `easyDivide` zerodivisionerror using try and except, would do the job.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra Don't abuse exceptions for normal events.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `complex_divide` function to:

```
def complex_divide(list_of_numbers, index):
    denominator = list_of_numbers[index]

    if denominator != 0:
        return [item / denominator for item in list_of_numbers]

    return [0 for _ in list_of_numbers]
```

`easy_divide` function can be skipped.